# Frame-bundle reduction from spinor-bundle reduction

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, fibre-bundles, spin-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a $d$-dimensional Riemannian oriented, spin manifold, and let us denote by $F(M)$ its frame bundle, by $SP(M)$ its spin bundle and by $S = P(M)\times_{\rho}\Delta$ its spinor bundle, where $\rho\colon Spin(d)\to\Delta$ is the corresponding spinor representation. My question is:

When a reduction on $SP(M)$ implies a reduction on $F(M)$ and vice-versa?

For example: let us suppose that $M$ is seven-dimensional and equipped with a nowhere vanishing real spinor. Then, the spin bundle $SP(M)$ is reduced from $Spin(7)$ to $G_{2}$, the stabilizer of the spin-group action. In that case, since $G_{2}$ is connected an simply connected, its image inside $SO(n)$ by the map of the double-cover $\pi\colon Spin(7)\to SO(7)$ is a unique connected and simply connected subgroup of $SO(7)$ which can be denoted by the same symbol, since $\pi$ gives an isomorphism between them. Therefore in this case, a reduction on the spin bundle implies a reduction on the frame bundle. I would like to understand what are the conditions "if and only if" for this to happen in general, in both directions.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of $S$ in your post. This seems to be rather standard structure group reduction/extension business, but you should be more specific. Given the covering $\operatorname{Spin}\to SO$, what kind of subgroups in the two do you want to consider?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, in one sense, this is always true.  If $Q\subset SP(M)$ is a principal right $H$-bundle, where $H\subset\mathrm{Spin}(n)$ is a subgroup, then $\delta(Q)\subset F(M)$ is a principal right $\pi(H)$-bundle, where $\pi(H)\subset\mathrm{SO}(n)$ is the image subgroup.  (Here, I am using $\delta:SP(M)\to F(M)$ to denote the double cover that the OP didn't name or notate.)

The OP may, however, have intended to ask a different question, such as, "When does having a nonvanishing spinor field on $M$ imply a reduction of structure group of $M$?".  The answer to this is "When $\mathrm{Spin}(n)$ acts transitively on the unit sphere in its spinor representation $\mathbb{S}$.". (However, one must be precise about that is meant by this.  People sometimes say "$\mathrm{Spin}(8)$ acts transitively on the unit sphere in its spin representation." when they mean "$\mathrm{Spin}(8)$ acts transitively on the unit sphere in each of its semi-spin representations.")

**Added at the request of the OP:**  Let $(M,g)$ be an oriented, spinnable Riemannian $d$-manifold, with $\beta: F(M)\to M$ being its oriented orthonormal frame bundle and $\delta:SP(M)\to F(M)$ being a double cover that defines a spin structure on $M$.  Let $\pi:\mathrm{Spin}(d)\to\mathrm{SO}(d)$ be the double cover and let $\mathbb{S}$ be the spinor space, with $\rho:\mathrm{Spin}(d)\to\mathrm{SO}(\mathbb{S})$ the spin representation.  Then $S = SP(M)\times_\rho\mathbb{S}$ is the spinor bundle of the spin structure, so that a spinor field, i.e., a section of $S\to M$ is represented by a smooth map $s:SP(M)\to \mathbb{S}$ that satisfies $s(u\cdot g) = \rho(g^{-1})s(u)$ for all $u\in SP(M)$ and $g\in \mathrm{Spin}(n)$.  The section is nonvanishing if and only if $s$ is nonvanishing, in which case, we can normalize, replacing $s$ by $s/|s|$ to get a unit spinor field.  Thus, we can assume $|s| = 1$, i.e., that $s$ maps $SP(M)$ to the unit sphere in $\mathbb{S}$.  Now, we can ask, when can we find an element $v\in\mathbb{S}$ with $|v|=1$, such that $s^{-1}(v)\subset SP(M)$ defines a principal subbundle of $SP(M)$ for some subgroup $H\subset \mathrm{Spin}(d)$.  Well, the only possibility for $H$ would be the $\rho$-stabilizer of $v$, i.e., the subgroup $H = \{ g\in \mathrm{Spin}(d)\ |\ \rho(g)v = v\}$.  But this will only work if $s$ takes values in the orbit $\rho\bigl(\mathrm{Spin}(d)\bigr){\cdot}v$.  Now, this will always be true if $\mathrm{Spin}(d)$ acts transitively on the unit sphere in $\mathbb{S}$.  Unfortunately, that happens only when $d\in\{2,3,5,6,7,9\}$. In the two cases $d = 4$ and $d=8$, you don't have transitivity because, as a representation of $\mathrm{Spin}(d)$, the space $\mathbb{S}$ is the direct sum of two irreducible sub-representations: $\mathbb{S}=\mathbb{S}_+\oplus\mathbb{S}_-$, corresponding to the fact that a spinor field is the sum of two 'semi-spinors'.  It turns out that, in these two cases, $\mathrm{Spin}(d)$ does act transitively on the unit spheres in $\mathbb{S}_\pm$, so you get a structure reduction when there is a nonvanishing semi-spinor.

Comment: Thanks, as usual. Could you please elaborate a little bit this:

"When $Spin(n)$ acts transitively on the unit sphere in its spinor representation $\mathbb{S}$."

By the way, what about the other direction? If I am not mistaken, in the $G_{2}$ case, the $G_{2}$-reduction of the frame bundle can be "lifted" to a $G_{2}$-reduction on the spin bundle. I guess this question can be reformulated as when the set of tensors defining the reduction on $F(M)$ come from spinors through the isomorphism $S\otimes S = \Omega^{\bullet}(M)$. This is precisely what happens in the $G_{2}$-case.

Comment: Why does it fail to be transitive for $d\ge 10$?

Comment: @ChrisGerig:  For $d\ge 11$, one has $\mathrm{dim}(\mathbb{S}) > \mathrm{dim}\bigl(\mathrm{Spin}(d)\bigr) + 1$, so transitivity fails for dimension reasons.  For $d=10$, it would be possible for dimension reasons, but explicit calculation shows that the action of $\mathrm{Spin}(10)$ on the unit sphere in $\mathbb{S}\simeq \mathbb{R}^{32}$ has cohomogeneity $1$.  See www.math.duke.edu/~bryant/Spinors.pdf for details.

Comment: @RobertBryant: Thanks Robert. I am confused about something. When you say that $\rho\colon Spin(d)\to SO(\mathbb{S})$ I was assuming that this is already an irrep of $Spin(d)$, and that one constructs the spinor bundle from this irrep. However, from your explanation it looks like you are assuming that this representation is a complex irrep of the Clifford algebra $Spin(d)\subset Cliff(d)$, which splits for even $d$ as two complex irreps of $Spin(d)$ of definite chirality, as you wrote. Not only that, for $d=8k$, there are real chiral irreps.

Comment: By the way, shouldn't it be $\rho\colon Spin(d)\to End(\mathbb{S})$? And since (if I am not mistaken) the representation is unitary then one can write $\rho\colon Spin(d)\to U(\mathbb{S})$.

Comment: @RobertBryant: Thanks for the clarifications, I just wanted to understand the terminology. However now I am confused by something: you say that the spinor representation is the lowest faithful real representation. However, I was under the impression that the $Spin(d)$ group does not always admit real irreps. From 3.6.1 of Joyce's book on holonomy and calibrations I got the impression that real irreps for $Spin(d)$ only exist when $d=8k-1,8k,8k+1$. For example, what would be the real spin representation of $Spin(3)\simeq SU(2)$? (thanks for the patience).

Comment: @Bilateral: The spinor representation is the lowest dimensional *faithful* (real) representation of $\mathrm{Spin}(d)$ on which the nontrivial element in the kernel of $\pi: \mathrm{Spin}(d)\to\mathrm{SO}(d)$ acts as $-1$.  When $d\not\equiv0\ \mathrm{mod}\ 4$, this is irreducible, but when $d\equiv0\ \mathrm{mod}\ 4$ it is the direct sum of two representations, neither of which is faithful.  These representations are not always complex; this depends on $d\ \mathrm{mod}\ 8$.  Complex representations are a different story.  If you want the complex representations, you should specify this.

Comment: @RobertBryant: I think I understand now what you mean. It looks like that what I call (perhaps incorrectly) complex representations of $Spin(d)$ are real representations of $Spin(d)$ of complex type, namely they are real representations equipped with an invariant complex structure. Is this correct?

Comment: @Bilateral: This is a question of terminology. In my terminology, an irreducible representation is *always* real; it is *complex* if and only if the commuting ring contains a copy of $\mathbb{C}$; and it is *quaternionic* if and only if the commuting ring contains a copy of $\mathbb{H}$ (in which case the commuting ring has to be equal to $\mathbb{H}$). In general, the spinor representation is complex if and only if $d\ \mathrm{mod}\ 8$ is in $\{2,3,4,5,6\}$ and is quaternionic if and only if $d\ \mathrm{mod}\ 8$ is in $\{3,4,5\}$. This answer your question about $\mathrm{Spin}(3)$, I think.

Comment: @RobertBryant: Thanks Robert. Yes, it answers my question. If I am not mistaken, you are obtaining such real representations by restriction of the real representations of the real Clifford algebra $Cl(d)$, which are of the complex or quaternionic type depending also on the dimension. However, one can consider the complexified Clifford algebra $\mathbb{C}l(d)$, whose complex representations are very simple. These induce complex representations on $Spin(d)\subset \mathbb{C}l(d)$,irreducible in odd dimension a reducible in even. These are what you would call complex representations of $Spin(d)$?

Comment: @Bilateral:  Yes, those are what I would call the complex spin representations.  However, when you say 'very simple', you should be aware that this really only applies to the dimension formulae.  The actual orbit structure of the action defined by the representation can be quite complicated (and is, when $d$ gets large).

Comment: @RobertBryant: Thanks. The way I understood this, and now I am afraid it might not be correct, is that from the complex representations of $Spin(d)$ one can obtain all the others. For example, if $d=7$, the complex representation of $Spin(7)$ must have an invariant real structure which defines a unique real representation inside the complex one, and which coincides with the real representation induced by the real Clifford group $Cl(7)$. In particular, when the real representation of $Spin(d)$ is of complex type, then it is the same as the complex representation of $Spin(d)$.